# PWA with offline JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, offline, progressive-web-apps

I've copied the app from google tutorial: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/#8 and added a piece of code:

```
<button onclick="fWrite()">
    Test
</button>

<div id="test"> ABC </div>

<script>
    function fWrite()
    {
        if (document.getElementById("test").innerHTML == "ABC")
        {
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "DEF";
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "ABC";
        }

    }
</script>
```

But the script works only online. After adding the page to the home screen and downloading it, the button can't be pressed. How to make it work offline?

The site I want to work offline as an app: http://diverse.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: Did you upload the manifesto.json? Because I get this message: The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Maybe that's the reason why your code is not working.

Comment: Yes, maybe it's not available http://diverse.azurewebsites.net/manifest.json here, but I've got it there. I will try to upload these files on another server, maybe Azure is blocking it in some way.